# Where do I get benefits from usage App Startup library?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, app-startup

Where do I get benefits from usage *App Startup* library?

The documentation only tells us how to create an object and not how to use it

```
class MyPreferences : Initializer<SharedPreferences> {
    override fun create(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        val myPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
        return myPreferences
    }

    override fun dependencies(): MutableList<Class<out Initializer<*>>> {
        return mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

Then I want to use *myPreferences* instance somewhere

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val myPreferences = howToUseInstanceOfMyPreferencesThatAlreadyCreated()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Config class to manage preferences and have a single instance of it.

```kotlin
class Config(context: Context) {

    val myPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

    init {
        println("Config class is initialized")
    }
    
    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : Config? = null

        fun newInstance(context: Context) : Config {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: Config(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
        }

        fun getInstance() : Config {
            return INSTANCE ?: throw IllegalStateException("Config is not initialized")
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a single instance in the initializer class:

```kotlin
class ConfigInitializer : Initializer<Config> {
    override fun create(context: Context): Config {
        return Config.newInstance(context)
    }

    override fun dependencies(): MutableList<Class<out Initializer<*>>> {
        return mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

Than in your app you can use the shared pref as:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val pref = Config.getInstance().myPreferences
    }
}
```